# Square a combinatorial formula (binomial theorem)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

I have the following function

$$
f(a,b,c\mid k) = \binom{k}{l}a^l\binom{k-l}{m}b^mc^{k-l-m}[1-d^m]
$$
Upon application of the binomial theorem I get

$$
[a+b+c]-[a+bd+c]
$$
I do not wish to simplify this further.

I would also like to consider $f^2$. It is at this point I am unsure how to proceed, starting from my original expression. How would I rationalise this?